# Custom auto incrementing fields for string giving duplicate entries

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am currently working on an application that requires that every student registered in the system have a unique registration number upon registration which is auto incrementing for every registration. The registration number should be of the format "01/19" for the first student registered in 2019, "890/19" for 890th student etc.

The data for registration is uploaded from [kobo data collection](https://www.kobotoolbox.org/)  tool therefore it comes to my endpoint within very close time intervals as close to 200 submission can be done once.

I realized that out of 1000 records there are close to 27 duplicate registration numbers. This is how I have implemented the registration number generation logic

```
def registration_changeset(student, attrs) do
    student |> changeset(attrs) |> Accounts.add_registration_number()
 end
```

Then the Accounts context has the following code for adding registration number

```
def add_registration_number(changeset) do
  struct = changeset.data.__struct__
  registration_number =
  case struct |> last() |> Repo.one() do
    nil -> _create_new_registration_number()
    resource -> _increment_registration(resource.registration_number)
  end

  put_change(changeset, :registration_number, registration_number)
end
```

I am betting on the last created student to be having the latest registration number in the above case

Is there a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit of synchronized code here :)

Create a dedicated process that will serve the single purpose: producing numbers. [`GenServer.handle_call/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#c:handle_call/3) already does whatever you need, the process mailbox is the perfect queue and OTP would do everything for you.

```rb
defmodule MyApp.RegNumHelper do
  @moduledoc false

  use GenServer

  def start_link(opts),
    do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: name)

  def add_registration_number(changeset),
    do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:reg_num, changeset})


  @impl true
  def init(opts), do: {:ok, opts}

  @impl true
  def handle_call({:reg_num, changeset}, _from, state) do
    # your logic assigning changeset
    {:reply, changeset, state}
  end
end
```

This approach has another advantage: since the process is already stateful you do not actually need to query the DB every time. Just query it on process start and save the current number into `state`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is that you could just let the auto-incremented ID be the first part of the registration number and store the two-digit year as a field by itself. Then in the model you would simply have a method 'get_registration_number' that composes the two. This resolves the duplicate problem.

The downside is that you would then have, say 890/19 as the last student in 2019, and then 891/20 as the first student in 2020 instead of 01/20. But your example doesn't quite appear to handle that case either, and it is implied, but not clear, that this is a requirement.

Which if it is, you could instead of letting the ID be the first part, create a column that auto-increments as before (id_num, say) and then when the year changes reset the next value to 1 on that column. If you wanted to be paranoid you could say the 'id_num' column and the 'two_digit_year' column together form a unique key.

TL;DR: The easiest way to handle this is to let the database handle it.